# SQL Server : unique identifier list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a table in SQL Server that contains all of the possible combinations of the following, ensuring each record is unique:

```
Alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, numeric, numeric numeric
```

E.g.

```
AAAA000-ZZZZ999
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One brute force option would be to use letter and number tables and then do a series of cross joins.

Answer (score 5):

Here are zillions of combinations.  But you can do this as:

```
with alpha as (
      values ('A'), ('B'), . . ., ('Z')
     ),
     digits as (
      values ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
     )
select (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + d1 + d2 + d3)
from alpha a1 cross join
     alpha a2 cross join
     alpha a3 cross join
     alpha a4 cross join
     digits d1 cross join
     digits d2 cross join
     digits d3;
```

The `. . .` is for the remaining letters.  There are shortcuts to generating them via recursive CTEs or other methods (but listing them explicitly does make the intention of the query clearer).

I should add that there are 456,976,000 combinations so don't be surprised if generating all of them takes a certain amount of time.